# Laravel - Unique Request Rules allows duplicate

Tags: laravel, rules

In Laravel-5.8 I applied Rules Request for multiple fields as shown below:

```
public function rules() 
{
    return [
        'goal_type_id'  => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query
                    ->where('employee_id', 1)
                    ->where('appraisal_identity_id', 1);
                })
        ],                  
        'appraisal_doc'  => 'nullable|mimes:doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,pdf,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,|max:5000',
        'weighted_score' => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',            
    ];
}
```

This is mysql query:

```
ALTER TABLE appraisal_goals
ADD CONSTRAINT appraisal_goals_uniq1 UNIQUE KEY(goal_type_id,appraisal_identity_id,employee_id);
```

This is meant for create. From the code the combination of goal_type_id, employee_id and appraisal_identity_id are unique.

When I click on submit in create blade, it allows duplicate.

1. How do I resolve this?
2. Also, how do I write the one for update?

> Please note that my route is appraisal_goal

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for update

```
public function rules() 
{
    $appraisal_goal_id = 'take your appraisal_goals id here from request';
    return [
        'goal_type_id'   => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals')->ignore($appraisal_goal_id, 'id')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query
                    ->where('employee_id', 1)
                    ->where('appraisal_identity_id', 1);
            })
        ],
        'appraisal_doc'  => 'nullable|mimes:doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,pdf,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,|max:5000',
        'weighted_score' => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',          
 ];
}
```

Comment: How about create

Comment: What you have done is okay for your create. You need another rule for the update that I have provided.

I think this is better to make a separate rule for create and update